# How to extract Specific Numbers from String in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to extract the number present in a string in which the string comes in a different way. The String I receive and expected output is mentioned below.

| PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION | EXPECTED PACK SIZE | CURRENT_RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PRODUCT A 3 CHEESE SLICE 170 GM | 170 | 3170 |
| PRODUCT B SUGAR 1.3KG (CL) | 1300 | 13 |
| PRODUCT C CHEESE SLICES 12X156GM | 156 | 12156 |
| PRODUCT KETCHUP BOTTLE 200GM (CL) | 200 | 200 |
| PRODUCT KETCHUP 1.3KG (CL) | 1300 | 13 |
| KITCHEN 88 KALE & CHIA BASMATI RICE 150GM | 150 | 88 |

I tried using below transformation in Snowflake SQL, but it is only extracting all the numerical literals from the string.

`REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(UPPER(PRODUTC_DESCRIPTION),'GM',1),'[^[:digit:]]')`

I need to run the code in Snowflake, Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does every sting contain a measure(eg KG) and quantity in the form quantity measure and is it always at the end?

Comment: Quantity along with Unit need not be in end, hence for this purpose I used SPLIT_PART to get to the unit part. Also the units are not consistent, but it is limited to GM, KG, K

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fUaPFV/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might be helpful:

```
select PRODUTC_DESCRIPTION, 
TRIM( regexp_substr( PRODUTC_DESCRIPTION, '([\\.\\d ]*\\d+ *)((KG|K|GM))',1,1,'e')) as packsize_num,
TRIM( regexp_substr( PRODUTC_DESCRIPTION, '[\\.\\d ]*\\d+ *((KG|K|GM))',1,1,'e')) as packsize_unit,
IFF( packsize_unit IN ('K','KG'),  packsize_num * 1000, packsize_num  ) packsize
from values 
('PRODUCT A 3 CHEESE SLICE 170 GM'),
('PRODUCT B SUGAR 1.3KG (CL)'),
('PRODUCT C CHEESE SLICES 12X156GM'),
('PRODUCT KETCHUP BOTTLE 200GM (CL)'),
('PRODUCT KETCHUP 1.3KG (CL)') tmp(PRODUTC_DESCRIPTION);

+-----------------------------------+--------------+---------------+----------+
|        PRODUTC_DESCRIPTION        | PACKSIZE_NUM | PACKSIZE_UNIT | PACKSIZE |
+-----------------------------------+--------------+---------------+----------+
| PRODUCT A 3 CHEESE SLICE 170 GM   |          170 | GM            |      170 |
| PRODUCT B SUGAR 1.3KG (CL)        |          1.3 | KG            |    1,300 |
| PRODUCT C CHEESE SLICES 12X156GM  |          156 | GM            |      156 |
| PRODUCT KETCHUP BOTTLE 200GM (CL) |          200 | GM            |      200 |
| PRODUCT KETCHUP 1.3KG (CL)        |          1.3 | KG            |    1,300 |
+-----------------------------------+--------------+---------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks Atil, Approach looks good.. I have added two more sample records for which this is failing.

Comment: @VipendraSingh updated the solution

Comment: That helps, Thanks a lot Atil. You have very good understanding of Regex. Can you suggest some course/link or anything where I can learn it ?

Comment: @VipendraSingh I can't suggest a link/course but I found this and it seems promising: https://regexlearn.com/ I think you learn more when you keep using it

Comment: Hi @Gokhan, one little help, I see there is one more sample data for which it is failing, Can you check once ? I have updated the sample records (last one) in question .
"KITCHEN 88 KALE & CHIA BASMATI RICE 150GM"

Comment: The problem is about recognizing K as a kilo. Are you sure if K is used as a unit? is there any 10 K or is it always 100 KG? If not, removing the middle K in (KG|K|GM) fixes the issue.

Comment: actually in some cases K is coming as one of the unit